# Is there a way to submit a form, and then open a new window?

Tags: javascript, form-submit, new-window

I'd like to be able to do this without using window.open because I've been told that gets caught by popup blockers. Would it be possible to use javascript to alter the submit button in some way (like add a target="_blank") or something to achieve this?

Comment: Add your code what you have tried as of now

Comment: Right now I'm using meta refresh to take them off the page

Comment: But I'd prefer to open a new window instead? Is there a meta refresh version of taking a user off the page but in a new window?

Comment: you should use DOM or better [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: I'm pretty new at this, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: he means don't open a new window at all, but instead open a modal, which is like a new window, but is part of the existing page DOM and so does not cause the popup problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new window will not get blocked by the browser if `window.open` was called as a result of user action.

Example:

```
// Find the button you want to bind to 
var button = document.getElementById('test');
// Add a click event listener
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
});
```

All major browsers will allow the above to open a new window / tab.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gft4jzqg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either control what happens when you submit the form by putting a `onsubmit` on the form, or use an `<a target="_blank">` as a form submit button.

if you choose the first option:

```
<form onsubmit="formSubmit()"> </form>
<script>function formSubmit(){code here}</script>
```

or the second option:

```
<form id="form">
<!--place your inputs here -->
<a href="google.com" target="_blank" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()"></a>
</form>
```